# Intellij IDEA 13: Error compiling sbt component

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven Scala project created with archetype:

```
  archetypeGroupId=org.scala-tools.archetypes
  archetypeArtifactId=scala-archetype-simple
  version=1.3
```

I'm getting this when trying to run a simple main method:

```
Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.8.0.final-51.0'
```

The Maven build works fine though... I'm new to Scala so this is probably some simple problem.

Answer (score 5):

The good people over at JetBrains had a solution:

> Looks like this plugin is quite old and generates pom with an old
>   scala version. Try 2.10.0

Meant to post this sooner but I forgot about this question.