# Scala Compiliation error with intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compilation

I'm trying to compile a mixed java-scala code using intelliJ 14.1.4

but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Error Compiling SBT component 'compiler-interface-2.9.2-52.0'
```

I have tried to down grade my scala-compiler version but this didn't helped.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What versions of scala and sbt are you using? Looks like Scala 2.9.x so you could try upgrading to Scala 2.10. OP here had a similar problem with an older version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497806/intellij-idea-13-error-compiling-sbt-component

Comment: sbt version 0.13.8
scala version 2.10.4 (from cmd)

Comment: Maybe your IntelliJ or the Project you are trying to compile still run on an older version. On your project you can check under Project Structure -> Global Libraries or in your build.sbt, if available

Comment: what was there under scala was scala 2.11
i removed it and still this doesn't work...

Comment: Well 2.11 is newer than 2.10, so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: @thwiegan your comment should be the solution to this.

Comment: I had the same problem, and it has been solved by changing from java 14  to java 1.8

Answer (score 32):

I had the same issue:

> Error Compiling the SBT component 'compiler-interface-2.11.8-53.0'

I was running Java 9,jdk-9.0.4, I fixed this by going back to Java 8, jdk1.8.0_161

Comment: I faced with the same issue. However by going back to JDK1.6.0_181, the issue remains. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 17):

this confuse me a lot

in idea you have two jdk setup

one is

[image]

another is

[image]

you need to set this two both to jdk1.8 or will always be conflict with your scala.

Comment: For people who don't want to click through, this is a reminder that the project JDK and run configuration both need to match (and be the right version for your project). Even 6 years later this was helpful...

Comment: Once again, if you don't want to open images and search for settings, here are the steps---> Right click on your project name --> Click on 'Open Module Settings' --> Under project settings withing Project and Module change the setting back to JDK needed

Answer (score 16):

To add to Amy's and other answers, there are three places where JDK is involved. The first two are in the Project Settings, the third is
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Scala Compiler -> Scala Compile Server (if enabled).
If this problem arises, check these three are the same.

Comment: Thanks for also mentioning the Scala Compile Server. This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you have the JDK-1.8 set in the following places.

```
Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK
Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Module SDK
```

Add/Select JDK-1.8 in

```
Project Settings -> SDKs
```

Comment: Does not work with openJDK 11 as of date.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have the JDK-1.8 set in the following places.
Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK
Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Module SDK
Add/Select JDK-1.8 in

Project Settings -> SDKs

The first two are in the Project Settings, the third is Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Scala Compiler -> Scala Compile Server (if enabled). If this problem arises, check these three are the same.

Make Sure that Java versions are same every where,

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe to Intellij's compiler. Prefer compiling them in a console.

Try to re-import the project to Intellij.

Comment: Indeed, the compilation already worked on the console but IntelliJ would not compile, and a re-import solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

The issue was due to 2 different dependencies, which imported 2 different scala versions, and then scala 2.11 was compiled with scala 2.9 which led to the error.

maven dependencyManagement solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs due to incompatibility in versions of the libraries used.
The solution is to ensure that java version, scala version, any other library version are all compatible with each other. mvnrepository can be used for checking.

Answer (score 0):

Also, please make sure you are using compatible Scala and Jdk version. like -
[JDK-Scala Version compatibility table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNA8A.png)

Please refer - https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error when I run the old project https://github.com/dpp/simply_lift

it was from 2010.. I must revert my java to 1.7 and update the Scala version from **2.11.6** to **2.11.12** , add it to Project Settings-> Modules

Then I can start the project ...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

File --> Invalidate caches/restart was also needed for me in addition to fixing libraries.